# Couldn't acquire root after running superboot

Tags: rooting, fastboot, bootloader, motorola-moto-g2

I've already done all steps for getting root at my `MotoG (2nd generation)` but still can't acquire the privilege.

- Unlocked bootloader:

  - Started developer mode + USB debug
  - Ran fastboot oem unlock UNLOCK_CODE

I'm even getting the "warranty void" message at startup, so it seems that the bootloader was really unlocked.

- Getting root privileges:

  - Downloaded `r2-motog-superboot`
  - Went to fastbook screen again with developer mode + UDB debugging
  - ran `sudo chmod +x superboot-linux.sh` and `sudo ./superboot-linux.sh`

The `superboot-linux.sh` has only these two commands:

```
 chmod +x fastboot-linux
 ./fastboot-linux boot boot.superboot.img
```

The phone restarted but superuser wasn't installed and no root privilege acquired. What can I be missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because that way (superboot) is old and doesn't work on the current software releases, TBH I am surprised it still boots at all after that, probably because you just just manually booted it and didn't flash it.

I will assume this is the Titan (non-LTE) version. The proper way to do this if you are unlocked is simple... Download the latest [TWRP](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g-2014/orig-development/recovery-twrp-2-8-2-0-touch-recovery-t2979149) for your device and [SuperSU](https://download.chainfire.eu/supersu/) and place the later on your device.

Start the device in bootloader mode, and in the terminal enter

`sudo fastboot boot twrp.img` <- Replace filenames with appropriate ones for your installation

Once TWRP is loaded, Install (flash) SuperSU ZIP you downloaded from the link above.

Reboot, enjoy root on your device.

BTW, you didn't mention your Linux distro or fastboot version, you may need to get the current releases from the Android Dev package if your repos do not have current ones.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the help. I'm using Arch Linux. My fastbootversion is: 09a0d98bebce-android. Btw, you said "install (flash) SuperSU". How to do this kind of installation?

Comment: In TWRP there is a button labeled "Install", you press it, then use the file browser to find the SuperSU ZIP file, and swipe to flash it. By fastboot version I meant the version of the fastboot executable on your PC. To make sure you have the latest adb/fastboot, make sure you have the `android-tools` package installed from the official repos.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't able to execute twrp and just found out now why. I'm having some errors when downloading the file from "twrp.me". I just checked out the md5sum to be sure. Every file I download from there just downloads the first 5.1KBytes and I don't know why this is happening. Do you know any other place where I can download twrp? Thanks
Edit: Also tried to download using wget but also only the first 5k were downloaded ( the site says its size is about 9MBytes, there is something wrong I guess)

Comment: @Fabiotk Not sure what to say, I was able to download `twrp-3.0.2-1-titan.img` with no issues from https://dl.twrp.me/titan/twrp-3.0.2-1-titan.img.html and md5 matches, 8.1mb

Comment: Yes, that's really weird. Just to proof I'm not lying, there are some other people that were having this problem too as discussed here: http://goo.gl/8DtXE1

Comment: @Fabiotk never thought you were lying... Just saying it works as best I can see.  Try this temp link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-tbsbTajV1UenpIa2FuSUo2VDg/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I tried to flash boot/recovery on this twrp image and now my cellphone is not booting anymore. When I turn it on it falls on fastboot everytime. Do you know how can I proceed? I tried also to factory recover but also the same error

Comment: @Fabiotk what did you do exactly? And what device (model number) and exactly what files? You aren't giving me much to work with... Remember there are dedicated forums for the G2 on XDA.

Comment: Hey, I used this file I downloaded at tempo link you gave me. I tried both comands: `sudo fastboot flash recovery twrp.img` and `sudo fastboot flash boot twrp.img` to boot directly into it. Both gave the error "mismatched partition size". After that, can't boot anymore on my phone.

Comment: @Fabiotk there are multiple models of the Moto G 2014, titan isn't the only one, I only used it as an example... There is titan, Thea, peregrine, etc... Which one do you have or what model number? T

Comment: my model is Moto G2 XT1033